# How to call systemctl restart app.service from Python?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I have a Python app that has a PyTorch model, which breaks once in a while. `sudo systemctl restart app.service` fixes the issue. I am studying the reasone of the problem, but I need a hotfix. So, how totell the app to `restart service if you (Flask app) return an error message`?